# How to convert timestamp to normal time in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to convert timestamp from my mysql table in to normal time.

I've tried looking for information on the internet but there is only solutions for timestamps that you entered by hand

```
<?php
//setting header to
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'bitcoin');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
  die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT Kaina, Laiko_Kodas FROM localbtc LIMIT 200");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row /*("SELECT date_format(Laiko_Kodas) FROM localbtc")*/;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Are you sure you have put the files in the right folder? 404 error means that there's no file exists

Comment: Try to call a script that returns 'Hi!', and nothing else. Can you call that script? 404 is not found

Comment: What do you get as result from `print json_encode($data);`?

Comment: @BramVerstraten I think it prints the data in to my chart

Comment: I don't mean what the purpose of the data is, but what is the actual result? What do you get when you call this script directly? Also, what do you mean by "normal time"?

Comment: @BramVerstraten there is too much information to put it in

Comment: @BramVerstraten normal time is like, year:month:day:hour:minute

Answer (score 0):

```
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
  $data = array(); 
  $data2[]= $row['Kaina'];
  $datetime=$row['Laiko_Kodas'];
  $data2[] = date('M j Y g:i A', strtotime($datetime));
  $dtata[]=$data;
  }
```

Comment: @Valibhav S where is the $datetime ?

Comment: he has to add his variable name instead of that

Comment: in to which place?

Comment: That's why we need to know the result of `print json_encode($data);`. Can you please add it to the question so we can help you?

Comment: @BramVerstraten I just said that it prints the data in to the line chart

Comment: while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

Comment: @VaibhavS what is this?

Comment: you fetch as array. so fetch one by one and assign

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<?php
//setting header to
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'bitcoin');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = "SELECT Kaina, Laiko_Kodas FROM localbtc LIMIT 200";

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $row['Laiko_Kodas'] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($row['Laiko_Kodas']));
    $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: It goes then Laiko_Kodas as null

Comment: In the BitcoinDuomenys.php page